# python regular expression works in sample code but not the code required

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a project in which need to parse some web pages and for that I am using Beautifulsoup. I am able to get the information but there are many Unicode, newline, tab space characters and extra spaces in the string. I tried to use regular expression to remove these things. The script I wrote is working fine on a string which I declare in a simple script but it is not working on the real thing.

my code:

```
str = '\xa9 Copyright 2009-10 \n\t\t\t\t All Rights Reserved. (Best viewed in 1024x768 \n\t\t\t\tresolution & IE 6.0)                    break\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 \nChief Engineer'
reSpace = re.compile(' +')
reUni = re.compile( '(\\xa9|\\n|\\t|\\xa0)')
str = reSpace.sub(' ', str)
str = reUni.sub('', str)
print str
```

Thank u for replying.
my real code is:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
tagslist = [] # keeps track of the tags that have been encountered
filehandle = {} # stores the file handles for every rag
reUni = re.compile( '((\\xa9)|(\\n)|(\\t)|(\\xa0))')
reSpace = re.compile(' +')
page = "filename.html"  # html file which needs to be parsed
fread = open(page, 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(fread.read())
fread.close()
if re.match( r'.*\.htm$', page):    # removes the .html or htm to remove "." to be enable to create a folder named "filename"
    page = site+"_parsed/"+page[:-4]+"_data"
else:
    page = site+"_parsed/"+page[:-5]+"_data"
if not os.path.exists(page):    #creates the folder named "filename"
    os.makedirs(page)
for tag in soup.find_all():
    if tag.string:  #if the tag encountered has a child string or not
        #if tag is encountered for the first time than create the file to hold its strins and declare the file handle for it
        if tag.name not in tagslist:
            tagStrFile = page+ "/" + tag.name +"_str.txt"
            filehandle[tag.name] = "handle_" + tag.name
            vars()[filehandle[tag.name]] = open(tagStrFile, 'w+') #declare the file handle
            tagslist.append(tag.name)
            filehandle[tag.name] = vars()[filehandle[tag.name]]
        str = (repr(tag.string))
        str = str[2:-1]
        str = reUni.sub('', str)
        str = reSpace.sub(' ', str)
        if str == '':
                continue
        filehandle[tag.name].write(str)
        filehandle[tag.name].write("\n")
    for tag in tagslist:    #close all the files
        filehandle[tag].close()
```

a small part of the  data it creates:

```
INTRODUCTION
SETUP
\xa0STRUCTURE \n                OF THE ORGANISATION
 The Category wise position as on 31-03-2012 of the Sanctioned Strength \n        and the Vacant Posts.
Sr.No.
Name \n          of the Post/Designation
Sanctioned \n          Strength
```

thanks

Comment: Did you use `.strings` to get that value? Use `.stripped_strings` instead.

Comment: You'll need to show us how your code is not working on your real data; use `repr()` to give us a representation of the actual data you have and how it doesn't produce the expected output.

Comment: i tried using '.stripped_strings' but instead of giving actual data it is giving 'enerator object stripped_strings at 0x000000000265FEA0'.

Comment: That's because `.stripped_strings` is a generator. Use `''.join(obj.stripped_strings)`. But so is `.strings`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To collapse multiple whitespace (including the non-breaking space) to one, you just need one regular expression:

```
re.sub(ur'[\s\xa0]+', u' ', samplestr)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> samplestr = u'\xa9 Copyright 2009-10 \n\t\t\t\t All Rights Reserved. (Best viewed in 1024x768 \n\t\t\t\tresolution & IE 6.0)                    break\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 \nChief Engineer'
>>> re.sub(ur'[\s\xa0]+', u' ', samplestr)
u'\xa9 Copyright 2009-10 All Rights Reserved. (Best viewed in 1024x768 resolution & IE 6.0) break Chief Engineer'
```

Comment: xa0 is Non-breaking space, &#160; or &nbsp in HTML.